# How to make an If that detects transform: translate3d style

Tags: javascript, jquery, translate-animation

I want to write a condicional statement that detects if a div has less that  "transform": "translate3d(-650px,0,0)". The div is like this:

```
<div class="owl-stage" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); transition: 0.25s; width: 1055px; padding-left: 40px; padding-right: 40px;"></div>
```

I cant find the right way to write it. This doesnt work:

```
if ($(".owl-stage").css("transform") <= "translate3d(-650px, 0px, 0px)"){
   console.log("hello");
 }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what you meant by *less that*?

Comment: What I mean is a number less that -650, like -700.

Comment: Then you can check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if the [abscissa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate3d#Syntax) of the two values is lesser of not, then try

```
function getAbcissa(translate3dValue) {
  var value = translate3dValue.indexOf("matrix") != -1 ? parseInt(translate3dValue.split(",")[4]) : Number(translate3dValue.match(/((-?)\d+(?=px))/g)[0]);
  return value;
}

if ( getAbcissa($(".owl-stage").css("transform")) <= getAbcissa("translate3d(-650px, 0px, 0px)")){
   console.log("hello");
 }
```

> **tx**
>
> Is a  representing the abscissa of the translating vector.

**Demo**

```js
function getAbcissa(translate3dValue) {
  var value = translate3dValue.indexOf("matrix") != -1 ? parseInt(translate3dValue.split(",")[4]) : Number(translate3dValue.match(/((-?)\d+(?=px))/g)[0]);
  return value;
}

if (getAbcissa($(".owl-stage").css("transform")) <= getAbcissa("translate3d(-650px, 0px, 0px)")) {
  console.log("hello");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="owl-stage" style="transform: translate3d(-800px, 0px, 0px); transition: 0.25s; width: 1055px; padding-left: 40px; padding-right: 40px;"></div>
```